# Dynamic Gradient in Scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I wish to use dynamic gradient in scroll bar but it doesn't seem to work.

```css
/* Gradient Scrollbar */
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {

  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  animation: scroll-gradient 5s ease infinite;
  background-size: 200% 200%;
}

@keyframes scroll-gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}


body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #1c1b1b;
}
```

```html
<body style="min-height: 800vh;"></body>
```

The animation is not working. Also, the code doesn't seem to work on Firefox. Please refer to the above code.

Comment: You have 2 issues here: `-webkit-` is for webkit browser (Chrome, Safari, Opera). Firfox has the `-moz-` prefix. Secondly Firefox barely supports customization of scrollbars.

Comment: Is there a way to apply dynamic gradient?

Comment: Read the linked comment. It clearly says what is supported. Everything not listed is not supported

Comment: Alright, thank you!